# Grab one record per ID with multiple Lead values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
 ID |  Val   |  Quantity
----------------------
 1  |   A    |   11
 1  |   B    |   15
 1  |   B    |   19
 1  |   Z    |   45
 2  |   D    |   4
 2  |   E    |   25
 2  |   F    |   13
 2  |   Y    |   2
 3  |   G    |   10
 3  |   H    |   15
 3  |   I    |   19
```

I want to select the top record for each ID ordered by VAL, Quantity AND add the next 2 Val/Quantity within the sort as columns to that row. My expected output look like this:

```
 ID |  Val   |  Quantity  | VAL2  | Quantity2 | VAL3  | Quantity3
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |   A    |   11       |  B    |   15      |   B   |    19
 2  |   B    |   15       |  D    |   4       |   E   |    25
 3  |   C    |   19       |  G    |   10      |   H   |    15
```

I've almost done it using lead, but I don't know how to get rid of the rest of the records in my data-set, as I only want the top.

```
SELECT ID,
       VAL,
       Quantity,
      lead(VAL,1) over (order by VAL, Quantity ASC) as Val2,       
      lead(Quantity,1) over (order by VAL, Quantity ASC) as Quantity2, 
      lead(VAL,2) over (order by VAL, Quantity ASC) as Val3,       
      lead(Quantity,2) over (order by VAL, Quantity ASC) as Quantity3,   
FROM MY_TABLE
order by VAL, Quantity ASC
```

How can I only select the top record for each ID, while maintaining the lead records? Or is there a more elegant/efficient way to do this?

Comment: you can use `row_number()` and also provide your expected output.

Comment: how could I use row_number() to accomplish this? My expected output is the second data-set I posted. I'll edit it so it's more clear.

Comment: I have just put an example how you can use `row_number()` to get top record by ID.

Comment: Why are the values for `ID` = 2 not `D`, `E` and `F` and `ID` = 3 not `G`, `H`, `I`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it seems the expected output should actually be:

```
ID  VAL     QUANTITY    VAL2    QUANTITY2   VAL3    QUANTITY3
1   A       11          B       15          B       19
2   D       4           E       25          F       13
3   G       10          H       15          I       19
```

You can get this result with a CTE which generates the `LEAD` values, as well as a `ROW_NUMBER` for each set of values. You can then select the first row for each `ID` from the `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID,
         Val, Quantity,
         LEAD(Val) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Val, Quantity) AS Val2,
         LEAD(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Val, Quantity) AS Quantity2,
         LEAD(Val, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Val, Quantity) AS Val3,
         LEAD(Quantity, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Val, Quantity) AS Quantity3,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Val, Quantity) AS rn
  FROM MY_TABLE
) 
SELECT ID, Val, Quantity, Val2, Quantity2, Val3, Quantity3
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13ca3/3)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41) to define  the order of the rows within the same `ID`

```
with t as (
select ID, VAL, QUANTITY,
row_number() over (partition by ID order by VAL, QUANTITY) as rn
from tab)
select * 

        ID V   QUANTITY         RN
---------- - ---------- ----------
         1 A         11          1
         1 B         15          2
         1 B         19          3
         1 Z         45          4
         2 D          4          1
...
```

In the next step use [`PIVOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#GUID-05BB22CD-0F53-4C90-AE84-CE3F88DBD591) to get the best three values in one row.

```
with t as (
select ID, VAL, QUANTITY,
row_number() over (partition by ID order by VAL, QUANTITY) as rn
from tab)
select * 
from t
PIVOT
(MAX(VAL) as VAL, MAX(QUANTITY) as QUANTITY FOR RN IN (1 as "COL1" ,2 as "COL2",3 as "COL3") 
)

        ID C COL1_QUANTITY C COL2_QUANTITY C COL3_QUANTITY
---------- - ------------- - ------------- - -------------
         1 A            11 B            15 B            19
         2 D             4 E            25 F            13
         3 G            10 H            15 I            19
```

If the standar pivot column naming is not fine, simple add a next query and rename the columns.

Note that this query return the same result as apternative approach base on multiple `LEAD` columns, but *you get a bit better flexibility if you plan to vary the number of traced columns*.